# Can't search in Lucene 6.2 using Scala

Tags: mysql, scala, lucene, slick

I'm trying to index the data from MySQL(using Slick in Scala) using Lucene 6.2. Here is the code below

```
package oc.api.services

/**
  * Created by sujit on 9/7/16.
  */
import org.apache.lucene.document._
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer
import org.apache.lucene.index._
import org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher
import java.io.{File, IOException}
import java.nio.file.Paths

import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.event.{Logging, LoggingAdapter}
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import oc.api.utils.{Config, DatabaseService}
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.KeywordAnalyzer
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode
import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.{QueryParser}
import org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

class Indexer extends Config {
  implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem()
  implicit val executor: ExecutionContext = actorSystem.dispatcher
  implicit val log: LoggingAdapter = Logging(actorSystem, getClass)
  implicit val materializer: ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()

  val databaseService = new DatabaseService(jdbcUrl, dbUser, dbPassword)

  val notesService = new NotesService(databaseService)    

  def setIndex = {
    val IndexStoreDir = Paths.get("/var/www/html/LuceneIndex")
    val analyzer = new KeywordAnalyzer()
    val writerConfig = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer)
    writerConfig.setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE)
    writerConfig.setRAMBufferSizeMB(500)
    val directory = FSDirectory.open(IndexStoreDir)
    var writer = new IndexWriter(directory, writerConfig)
    val notes = notesService.getNotes() //Gets all notes from slick. Data is coming in getNotes()
    var doc = new Document()
    var count = 0

    val stringType = new FieldType()
    notes.map(_.foreach{
      case(note) =>
        doc = new Document()

        var field = new TextField("title", note.title, Field.Store.YES)
        doc.add(field)

        field = new TextField("teaser", note.teaser, Field.Store.YES)
        doc.add(field)

        field = new TextField("description", note.description, Field.Store.YES)
        doc.add(field)

        writer.addDocument(doc)
    })
    writer.commit()
  }

  def search(keyword: String) = {
    val IndexStoreDir = Paths.get("/var/www/html/LuceneIndex")
    var directoryReader = DirectoryReader.open(FSDirectory.open(IndexStoreDir))
    val analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer()

    val searcher = new IndexSearcher(directoryReader)

    val mqp = new QueryParser("title", analyzer) //MultiFieldQueryParser(filesToSearch,analyzer)
    val query = mqp.parse(keyword)

    val hits = searcher.search(query,10)
    val scoreDoc = hits.scoreDocs
    println(scoreDoc.length)
  }

}

object Indexer extends App {
  val index = new Indexer
  index.setIndex
  index.search("Donec")
}
```

The setIndex function is working as expected in provided Path. But While I search the index based on keyword, It throws 0 result. Is there any mistake in seach function? How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason here is probably a mismatch of your analyzers. You use the `KeywordAnalyzer` for indexing, which does not analyze at all. For search, you use the `StandardAnalyzer`. In your example, the query `"Donec"` will be parsed and analyzed to `title:donec` as if you;d used `new TermQuery(new Term("title", "donec"))`. This will only match documents with the exact title `donec`, since you've used the keyword analyzer at index time. You should try to use the same analyzer for indexing as well.

Another thing might be – and I can only only guess this – `notesService.getNotes()` might be a `Future[_]` (or a similar asynchronous type), given that it involves slick. If it is, you add all the documents in the call to `.map()`, scheduled to happen once the future resolved. The `writer.commit()` call however, happens in the calling thread, likely before you've added all documents, so you should move the commit into the `map` callback as well.

Comment: Here first thing, I'd done mistake in using KeywordAnalyzer.  Secondly, I used writer.commit inside Future map. This provided me the result. Thanks for your help. I've edited question with the correct code.

Comment: How can the above code be implemented using Thread for optimizing Indexing process?

Comment: @Sujit I'd suggest opening a new question for this.